# What the heck is wrong with my photos?

Tags: camera

So ... I got this puppy. And he's *cute* so I want to post pictures of him on the internet. I realize we could have a very long conversation about whether or not anyone wants to look at photos of my dang puppy, but I just want help uploading them.

I am pretty sure the problem is the photos -- but if I try to upload them via the Tumblr App, it fails silently (no post is made, no error logged). Text posts go up just fine. If I try to go through the browser, I get an error: `error uploading photo` that doesn't clarify much. If I email myself the photo and edit it in an editor I can post it but that's not a great workflow.

Has anyone else experienced this? Are there workarounds? I have an aging Samsung Galaxy S.

Note: I tried opening a few phone camera photos on my laptop (in ImageMagick) and I'm getting a weird error. It is basically the same for the three photos:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 1136 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 1129 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 1128 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
```

Why would my phone take corrupt photos?

Comment: Are you using the stock camera app?  Have you tried using a different camera app?

Comment: Am using the stock app.

Comment: Could you try a camera app from Play Store and try repeating the issue? If the error pops up, there is a problem with camera firmware/driver. If not, then there is a problem with stock camera app.